# java string pixel length differs on different systems

Tags: java, fonts, size, pixel

I get a pixel length of string according to the following scala code

```
val metrics = new FontMetrics(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, GOOGLE_SERP_FONT_SIZE)) {}
val bounds = metrics.getStringBounds(text, null)
bounds.getWidth.toInt
```

However, this value differs on CentOS7 and Windows10.

Why this happens?